# X.509 Certificate Authentication with C# WinForms WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, x509certificate

I have a C# application that contains a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser and a local keystore containing an X.509 certificate. I need to have the WebBrowser control use the X.509 certificate when communicating with the web application it displays. Looking over the documentation for the [WebBrowser control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser?view=netframework-4.8) and the underlying [ActiveX control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752040(v=vs.85)), I don't see a way to attach the certificate. Preferably, it would only be attached to the embedded control and not globally to Internet Explorer. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Let incompatible with Internet `WebBrowser` rest in peace. Consider using `WebView`/`WebView2` or `CefSharp`.

Comment: [GetSerializedClientCertContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/dd433051(v=vs.85)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) method of [IHttpNegotiate3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/dd433052(v=vs.85)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) interface.

Comment: That appears to be for IE8 and does not seem relevant to the WebBrowser control which is an ActiveX version of IE11.